Bluetooth page in settings is frozen in place
I'm having a problem with my settings interface, which consists of being unable to enable bluetooth. The switch is stuck and on the screen is displayed the following message : "No bluetooth found - plug a dongle to use bluetooth".
I've followed a number of fixes from other threads but it didn't change anything. Here is what I did already.
relevant note : I'm a gigantic newbie just got Ubuntu some time ago
Basic commands returning useful information :
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt update

.
rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

.
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-04-25 03:40:23 CEST; 15min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 3341 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8555)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 100ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─3341 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

I have done the following commands :
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl unmask bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
sudo systemctl mask bluetooth.service 
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
rfkill unblock all

&
sudo apt install --reinstall bluez gnome-bluetooth indicator-bluetooth pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
sudo systemctl status bluetooth
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
sudo systemctl start bluetooth

&
sudo apt-get remove bluez
sudo apt install bluez

& finally and I'm sorry for the long post but here is what lspci returns :
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne IOMMU
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne PCIe GPP Bridge
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Internal PCIe GPP Bridge to Bus
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir Device 24: Function 7
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp WD Blue SN550 NVMe SSD (rev 01)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Lucienne (rev c2)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir Radeon High Definition Audio Controller
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) Platform Security Processor
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Renoir/Cezanne USB 3.1
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor (rev 01)
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller

Thanks for anyone who went is way to get to the bottom of this post :') I'll stay available to answer any question one might have.
